# Google maps infowindow returning same value

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

This code is always returning last value on click How can I resolve this error? Please help me.

js:

```
<?php foreach($pets as $pet):?>
var markerData = { lat: <?php echo $pet['pet_lat']?>, lng: <?php echo $pet['pet_long']?>, text: '<div class="shadow-box"><h3 class="title" style="font-size:20px;"><?php if($pet["pet_cat"] == 2):?><?php echo $pet["pet_name"];?><?php else:?><?php echo "Please Help me";?><?php endif;?></h3><p class="subtitle"><?php if($pet["pet_cat"] == 2):?><?php echo $pet["english"];?><?php else:?><?php echo $pet["dog_english"];?><?php endif;?></p><div class="image"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Pet/view/<?php echo $pet["petid"];?>" id="listinglink" target="_blank"><img src="<?php $img = unserialize($pet["img"]); echo base_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $pet["pet_hidenum"]."/".$img[0]?>" class="img-responsive" id="centerimg"></a></div><div class="quick-info clearfix"><div class="left"><p><span class="icon" style="font-size: 12px;"><img src="<?PHP echo base_url();?>assets/images/location.png" alt=""></span><?php echo $pet["reg_postal"].",".$pet["reg_city"].",".$pet["reg_country"]?></p><?php if($pet["showtel"] == "Yes"):?><p><span class="icon"><img src="<?PHP echo base_url();?>assets/images/phone.png" alt=""></span> <?php $mobile_phone_number = unserialize($pet["mobile_phone_number"]); echo $mobile_phone_number[0];?></p><?php endif;?><?php if($pet["pet_type"] == "Lost"):?><p id="rewardon"><span class="icon"><img src="<?PHP echo base_url();?>assets/images/reward.png" alt=""></span> Reward:€ (EUR) </p><?php endif;?></div><div class="right"><p style="margin-top: 14px;"><img src="images/mini_logo.png" style="width:95px;" alt=""></p><p>37070 Days Ago</p></div></div></div>' }
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: markerData });
    marker.setIcon({
        <?php if($pet['pet_type'] == 'Found' && $pet['pet_cat'] == '1'):?>
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/icons/greenpin.png"
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if($pet['pet_type'] == 'Found' && $pet['pet_cat'] == '2'):?>
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/icons/greenpin2.png"
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if($pet['pet_type'] == 'Lost' && $pet['pet_cat'] == '1'):?>
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/icons/redpin.png"
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if($pet['pet_type'] == 'Lost' && $pet['pet_cat'] == '2'):?>
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/icons/redpin2.png"
        <?php endif;?>
    })
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'spider_click', function(e) {
      iw.setContent(markerData.text);
      iw.open(map, marker);
    });
    oms.addMarker(marker);
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

try doing this

```
var image;
  <?php if($pet['pet_type'] == 'Found' && $pet['pet_cat'] == '1'):?>
        image ={ url: "<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/icons/greenpin.png"}
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if($pet['pet_type'] == 'Found' && $pet['pet_cat'] == '2'):?>
        image ={url: "<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/icons/greenpin2.png"}
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if($pet['pet_type'] == 'Lost' && $pet['pet_cat'] == '1'):?>
        image ={url: "<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/icons/redpin.png"}
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if($pet['pet_type'] == 'Lost' && $pet['pet_cat'] == '2'):?>
       image ={ url: "<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/icons/redpin2.png"}
        <?php endif;?>
```

and within

```
marker.setIcon(image);
```